# Querying a propositional model

Tags: z3

I was browsing the OCaml API for Z3 at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/ml/Z3.html looking for a way of accessing the model returned by the solver satisfying a simple propositional formula, ie. just using the SAT part of Z3, not the "T" part eg. p or q might return a model p=true, q=false. The closest I could find was solver_get_model which returns a model. But i couldn't find any way of accessing the model, as the model type seems opaque. I did see a function for getting the intepretation associated with a function symbol (model_get_func_interp) but that's not quite what I want and even then I couldn't see what to do with the returned information (a func_interp), as this also seems to be an opaque type. About the only other way I could see was to convert the model to a string. Is this the only way?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

*(Fair warning: I've not used the OCaml API myself, so I'm partially guessing this from my experience with the C API.)*

Take a look at the function:

```
val model_get_const_interp : context -> model -> func_decl -> ast
```

The values to pass for `context` and `model` should be clear. Now you may wonder why you need to pass a `func_decl` when you are really looking for the value of a constant. The thing is, in the SMT world in general and in Z3 in particular, constants are just like functions with no arguments (hence the precondition `get_arity c a == 0` as shown in the doc).

This will return an (option type of an) AST. The next step is to check that AST against `true` or `false`. One way to do this is to call the function

```
val get_decl_kind : context -> func_decl -> decl_kind
```

You can then compare the result with `OP_TRUE` and `OP_FALSE`.

Note that another way to query models is to use

```
val model_eval : context -> model -> ast -> bool -> ast option
```

You can pass any AST to this function (e.g. p ∧ ¬q, etc.) and read out the result in the same way.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it. I'm currently using the SMT-LIB interface which IMHO seems much less complicated